# Element on TabView does not disappear after being deleted

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I have this class:

```
class PageViewModel:ObservableObject {
  @Published var cars = [Car]()   
  
  func delete(_ car:Car) {
    cars = cars.filter { $0 != car }
  }
  
}
```

Then I pass this class to a view called `PageView`, like this

```
@ObservedObject private var pageViewModel = PageViewModel()

var body: some View {
  PageView(pageViewModel)
```

This is `PageView`:

```
struct PageView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var pageViewModel:PageViewModel
  
  init(_ pageViewModel:PageViewModel) {
    self.pageViewModel = pageViewModel
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    TabView() {
      ForEach(pageViewModel.cars) { car in
        TopPanel(car, pageViewModel)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
          .padding(.bottom,60)
        
      }
    }
    .frame(height: 220)
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
  }
}
```

Note: `Car` is a `NSManagedObject`, so it is `@ObservableObject` by default. Here it is

**Car+CoreDataClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Car)
public class Car: NSManagedObject {
}
```

**Car+CoreDataProperties**

```
extension Car : Encodable {
  
  @nonobjc public dynamic class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Car> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Car>(entityName: "Car")
  }
  
  @NSManaged public var model: String?
  @NSManaged public var brand: String?
```

This is `TopPanel` and where the problem originates.

```
struct TopPanel: View {
@ObservedObject private var car:Car
@ObservedObject private var pageViewModel:PageViewModel
  
init(_ car:Car,
     _ pageViewModel:PageViewModel?) {
  self.car = car
  self.pageViewModel = model
}

var body: some View {
  Button(action: {
    pageViewModel.delete(car)
}, label: {
  Text("delete me")
})
```

Remember that the `TabView` is showing pages of `TopPanel` and this `TopPanel` has a button that allows the user to delete itself from the `TabView`.

The problem is that when I press delete on a given element, it continues to show on the `TabView` but one the dots on the `TabView` is deleted. If after that I try to delete a second one, I receive this message:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_TtC7SwiftUIP33_8825076C2763A50452A210CBE1FA4AF020PagingCollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:collectionViewAnimator:], UICollectionView.m:6982

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete and reload the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xacce8bbd6a5ce2d8> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1})'

How do I solve that?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem, `ForEach(model.cars)`. What is `model` here, it is clearly not your view model object judging by your posted code? Do you have two different data sources? If you instead try `ForEach(pageViewModel.cars)` does it work then?

Comment: sorry about that. That was a typo. pageViewModel is the model being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbelievable, I have discovered how to solve this, completely by chance.

Just add

```
    .id(pageViewModel.cars.count)
```

to the TabView. That will force it to update when an item is deleted.

Comment: Interesting, so when you remove a car the id changes and that change triggers TabView to refresh itself. I guess this knowledge could be useful in other scenarios as well

Comment: Yes, that is it. When count changes, id changes and SwiftUI is forced to render the whole thing again. Logical, but completely insane and I would never think about doing this by myself. Yes, that solves a lot of problems on other contexts like Lists, ScrollViews, etc.